# переполнение в цикле

Tags: java

имеем код

```
  for (byte i = 126; i>5 ; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

вывод

```
126
127
```

а вот если через while

```
byte i = 126;
        while (i>5){
        i++;
            System.out.println(i);
    }
```

вывод будет

```
127
-128
```

я предпологал , что после переполнения будет печатать от -128 до 5.
какая-то защита от переполнения в цикле? тогда почему while перескочил?

Comment: С чего бы ему продолжать бесконечно если `-128` меньше `5`?

Comment: @Alexey Ten что-то я и впрям сморозил)))

Answer (score -1):

Могу ошибаться, но у вас цикл будет выполняться бесконечно т.к. значение с которого начинается цикл будет всегда больше 5 . i++ будет наращивать значение и i >5 не сработает. Если вы хотите после 127 перейти на -128. То наверное нужно установить условие if ( i >= 128) i= -128

Comment: проверте в ide, прекращается работа при подходе к переполнению, и поробывал в while цикле инкремент поставить после вывода, тоже останавливается как в for после печати 127

Comment: А до какого значения ``i`` будет расти?

Comment: @Эникейщик посмотрел дебагере - доходит по 127, когда значение i меняется на -128 в условие записывается false и заканчивает работу

Comment: да не, с условием все понятно :) я ДядеВане вопрос задаю, он пишет, что i++ будеть наращивать значение бесконечно.

Comment: Ну i = 126. или -126 ?

Comment: Так 126 или -126? И в чем заключается рост, если 126 первоначальное значение?

Comment: Рост в том что 126 заведомо больше 5 или не так , i++ будет всегда пока цикл больше 5

Comment: 126 заведомо больше 5, это так. Но после 127 далеко не всегда следует 128. Иногда следует -128. И вот -128 уже меньше 5.

Comment: @Дядя Ваня байт от -128 до 127 . в цикле доходит до границы и когда перескакивает на -128 условие менятся на false и как сказал Alexey Ten С чего бы ему продолжать бесконечно если -128 меньше 5?